# Sewing gone wrong, despite following step by step from a tutorial

Tags: modeling, mesh, cloth-simulation

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/HPz5gk_AT6w) where I'm trying to make clothes for a character. It's been a slow process and the only problem is that I can't seem to grasp the entirety of how it works.

In the tutorial @17:32, after doing everything it turns out to look really neat in the video but I get this result:

[image]

This is what happens to the shorts instead and I've tried looking up other solutions such as resizing it, giving it more verts, etc.

[Download .blend](https://mega.nz/file/sO9TDapQ#44OKP0Ts6wOxnPbykAHU4AcCyP53HSScuuXCX-yT-PI)

Comment: This looks *exactly* like my attempts at using sewing!   3ds Max worked well for me and in blender I don't achieve success. I'll follow this in the hopes we see a solution.   I have found that if I duplicate the hi-poly character, decimate it into a low-poly equivalent, and use *that* as the collision object, I get *slightly* better results.  But still very unsatisfying.

Comment: @Irrelevant Cake  What happened to the body mesh? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNZSL.jpg) It's a very bad zig-zag ngon mesh and this causes a lot of shading issues. I would replace it with a clean base mesh. A good body mesh is just quads, which makes editing easier, has good shading, works well with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and deforms well in animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I often am frustrated by "blender sew" results, I decided to watch this good video and play around and made some progress, and perhaps playing with more params might yield better results.  Where I left off:

[image]

I tweaked several things.

For the Collision object (character mesh): I (further?) decreased the Outer thickness as he described in the video, increased the Friction somewhat.

For the shorts: I eventually widened them as they were not closing completely.  I decreased both Collision and Self C distances as mentioned in the video.  I then had to decrease the shrinking factor (I'm not sure why this is so sensitive).  I increased the Quality steps to 12.   I added a Subsurf Modifier and also did his recommended Shade Smooth.

If I'm forgetting something, I include the resulting [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qv3vxbkvctqpr8j/Shorts.blend?dl=0) (I see blender-exchange file upload is broken again today).  Also it's possible that some of my edits were unnecessary!

Comment: One more thing: the face orientation of the sewing pattern mesh is not correct. If you duplicate the (front) mesh to create the back side don't forget to flip the duplicated mesh (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj8vx.jpg). To fix it, switch to *Edit* mode, select everything (key A), press Alt+N, then select *Recalculate Outside*. The blue color must be outside, red must be inside.

Comment: @Blunder -- eurika: I was always trying to switch the normals of *both* sides to compare the results, which never helped!  The referenced video doesn't mention this.